# HttpUrlConnection.getStatusCode hangs forever (without exception)

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, httpurlconnection

I'm working in a Java ear application with a web application module. In this module there is a class that calls other web application (hosted in the same application server - Glassfish 2.1), through a `HttpUrlConnection`.

The problem is... When I click on the button which calls the method to invoke the other web application, it works fine. But, when  I open too many tags on browser, and click fast on the same button. This is, when I call the method often (to invoke the other web application). The method hangs on the line `HttpUrlConnection.getStatusCode()`.

I searched about this on Google... I has tried put the property `setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close")`, and the property `setReadTimeout(5000)`. But it does not work.

I tried to put a semaphore control on the method (which calls the other web application), so each call is independent of the others calls (I broke the simultaneity).

I do not know what is the problem exactly. But when I call the `HttpUrlConnection.getStatusCode()` too many times the method hangs forever (it does not return, and it does not throw any exception).

I'm doing a POST HTTP call. And I'm using JDK 6.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the method getResponseCode.  Try setting the connection timeout also.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
con.setReadTimeout(socketTimeout);
```

Comment: Yes. You are right about the method name. But I tryed this solution (setConnectTimeout). It does not worked.